# Integration of AngularJS and Bridgeit.js (mobile web app)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile

I am developing an angularJS web app where i need to scan a package from mobile device and i am using [bridgeit](http://bridgeit.mobi/demo/scan.html) for that.

In angular i wrote the following code to execute the functionality but it doesn't seems to work.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<input id="inp" />
<button id="scan" ng-click="scan()"> Scan </button>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
// inside angular controller
$scope.scan = funcction() {
    bridgeit.scan('scan', 'window.scan');
}

// in global scope
window.scan = function(event) {
    alert(event.data);
}
```

**Result**: bridgeit will able to scan the qr/bar code but its doesn't returning the value.

Comment: I am actually looking into how to do this for my own project. I will try to share my results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several tries, i found that the issue is with `hashtags` in URL.

Lets take an example using same code,

```
// inside angular controller
$scope.scan = funcction() {
    bridgeit.scan('scan', 'bridgeitCallback');
}

// in global scope
window.bridgeitCallback = function(event) {
    alert(event.data);
}
```

I have an url, like, `http://stackoverflow.com/#question` and i have a scan field inside that page. So when i scan the barcode, it change the URL to, something like,

`http://stackoverflow.com/#c=scan%3Fid%3Dscan%26&r=http%3A//stackoverflow.com%23icemobilesx&o=enc%3Dbase64&h=%26h%3D%2523/question%26c%3DbridgeitCallback%26seq%3D1432552876578`

More clearly,

```
http://stackoverflow.com/#c=scan{{some_uri_encode_characters}}/{{your_route,mine_is question}}/{{bridgeit_callback_method}}
```

Thus, it never able to have a successful `POST` callback.

I just enabled html5Mode in angular, with,

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and everything works like a charm.

Hope it helps the future users as well.

Comment: Glad you solved it. My barcodes were not storing any sort of URL so I was not having this issue.

Comment: Can we prevent bridgeit from storing URL. If yes, then update your answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Try giving the function on the global scope a name and passing that to bridgeit.

Right now you are just assigning it to a property on the window called scan

Also make sure you do not have the function inside of any other functions or hidden from the global scope in some way.

Brigeit evaluates a string on the webpage in order to call your function.

```
// inside angular controller
$scope.scan = funcction() {
    bridgeit.scan('scan', 'globalScan');
}

// in global scope
window.scan = function globalScan(event) {
    alert(event.data);
}
```

Update:

One other thing  that might help is to try creating your global function before you add the bridgeit script.

The key point though is that bridgeit handles the *string* you give it in an eval function and looks for it on the global scope.

Comment: Assigning function/method to any object property means that it can now be accessed as a function/method. I think, your code will behave same as that of mine.  Moreover, you created one more function, i.e, `window.scan` which is used nowhere.

Comment: I was trying to change as little as possible since I don't know what else you might be using the window.scan reference for. There is a difference between assigning a function a name and putting it into a variable. when you just assign it to a variable it is still technically an anonymous function it is just stored in a variable.

Comment: One other thing  that might help is to try creating your global function before you add the bridgeit script. The key point though is that bridgeit handles the string you give it with an eval function and looks for it on the global scope.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you define a callback method before bridgeit script. Meanwhile, i figure-out the problem, it because of hashtags. +1 for showing providing your suggestions. I also post my answer as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code I am using in my own program:

```
function bridgeitCallback(result)
{
    alert("result is: " +  JSON.stringify(result));
}

$(document).ready(function readyDoc()
{
    var scanButton = $('#scanButton');
    scanButton[0].addEventListener('click', function () {
        bridgeit.scan('scan', 'bridgeitCallback');
    });
});
```

This is working for me. I have just added it at the end of my main controller class outside of angular.

You should be able to take the section in the ready function and put it anywhere on the page.

Update:

Due to the way the web browsers work, your webpage will be refreshed when you return from the call to Bridgeit so you will need to figure out some way to store any information you need to keep.

Local storage would probably be the best option. The AmplifyJS library is a very simple way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried it with `hashtags` url. Whether bridgeit working with them or not??